# flag provided but not defined

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

Am starting off in blockchain development using the book **Mastering Blockchain A deep dive into distributed ledgers...**

Am using WSL.

```
$geth version
Geth
Version: 1.10.9-stable
Git Commit: eae3b1946a276ac099e0018fc792d9e8c3bfda6d
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.17
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=go
```

Am trying to start geth but am getting the error that the --rpc flag is not defined

This the command am trying to run:

`geth --datadir ~/etherprivate/ --networkid 111 --rpc --rpcapi 'web3,eth,net,debug,personal' --rpccorsdomain '*'`

This is the output am getting:

`flag provided but not defined: -rpc`

I tried to use geth documentation as specified here https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options,
but it seems like the rpc flags are not listed.

Any help on how it can be solved would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who may encounter such a problem in the future.
All geth versions after 1.10.8-stable do not support rpc options they have been replaced with http

For example:

**--rpc => --http**

**--rpcapi => --http.api**

**--rpccorsdomain => --http.corsdomain**

Answer (score 0):

It appears 1.10.9-stable version has a problem and is returning a -rpc error.
I attempted to use http in place of rpc, since rpc is now deprecated, but the error also occurs for http (flag provided but not defined: -http)

GETH 1.10.8-stable version works fine when running the geth command with --rpc.